# CSS fails to apply for the home page in <welcome-file-list>

Tags: html, css, jakarta-ee, web-applications, welcome-file

> Hello, I have a home page LoginPage.html in /WebContent/html/LoginPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jsStyle.css" />
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

I have configured the same in web.xml

```
</welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/html/LoginPage.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

> Problem: When I am trying to access the file from the home page
>   URL
>  http://localhost:8080/Project/
>   **It fails to apply the CSS.**
>  Whereas when I access through the location specific URL 
>   http://localhost:8080/Project/html/LoginPage.html
>   **CSS is applied.**

***Hence, CSS fails to apply while loading the welcome page; I tried multiple alternatives. Kindly help.***

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the correct CSS file (file path, filename)? Using `../` means that you are going one directory up from where your HTML file is. And using your example, opening the file on `Project` directory runs the CSS, meaning your HTML file is located here, and your CSS file is located on `localhost:8080/css` directory

Comment: I tried just now, but it fails to apply. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jsStyle.css" />` since now, css folder is inside html.

Comment: Can you try inspecting your document? Try viewing the page source so you can see the links of the assets. Then try clicking on the underlined link of your CSS. You may find clues on why it doesn't get loaded once you open your resource.

Comment: Yeah that is a good idea, I am trying out some combination. Thanks. Will update once I finish.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./html/css/jsStyle.css" />` this did the trick. Now its loading for the Home Page. CSS URL is `http://localhost:8080/Project/html/css/jsStyle.css` But when i go the specific URL, it fails. CSS URL in this case is: `http://localhost:8080/Project/html/html/css/jsStyle.css`     'html' is coming twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your css file location has to be relative to the html file.I think currently you have your css file inside projects folder. If you want to access the css when you are using http://localhost:8080/Project/ your css path has to be `css/jsStyle.css`. If it doesn't work please update your folder tree structure.

Comment: WebContent/css/jsStyles.css;  WebContent/html/LoginPage.html

Comment: I made the change like you said, even now it fails to apply in the home page; but it is applying for the specific URL.

Comment: Do you find any console error like fail to load `css/jsStyle.css`?

Comment: Yes, it fails to load CSS.

Comment: I am damn sure it's your path. For now try to load the css file while keeping it in the same location where you html exists and load `jsStyle.css`. If possible can you update me with the tree structure. I mean like a screenshot...

Comment: also you can use absolute path to load the css. But the problem is you have to change the path for each and every time when you change the domain

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But the CSS is applying for the href value: [./css/jsStyle.css] for homeURL(http://localhost:8080/Advanced_MySQL/) or [../css/jsStyle.css] for specificURL(http://localhost:8080/Advanced_MySQL/html/LoginPage.html). It is not applying for both the cases.

Comment: You are loading two locations and referring  a same location url for your css. href will load the relative link to the current url. It's not possible to load your css in both places.

Comment: Provide  the absolute path to the `href`. There you can get your problem solved

Answer (score 0):

> I found the solution to the problem. 
>   ***The Home page must be in the root folder. /WebContent*** 
>   I made CSS references changes accordingly.

Thank you,
JJ